# aspect imageview fill, label coinciding with image

Tags: ios, swift3

I have an image and below it label in scrollview all, the image is aspect fill.Once image increases in size, the label that i have spaced to image by 8 comes on top of the image.I want my label to be below the image, no matter how the image resizes from url.

scrollview->view--> imageview below it label

imageview being aspect fill.

Comment: imageView.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: not the solution i need, because i dont want to clip. i want the entire image to show as is from server side.

Comment: You need to show the constraints on your image, most likely will have to link height / width constraints and update them when you get the image after you know the size of the image.

Comment: Have you tried AutoLayout, binding y Origin of label with Imageview?

Comment: Use autolayout is selected under deployment target.

Comment: I think you want to use AspectFit rather than AspectFill